# Determination of correct CSS selector for rvest to scrape realtor.com

Tags: css, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape information from realtor.com at the following address for an example home in Des Moines, IA.

http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/2419-Hart-Ave_Des-Moines_IA_50320_M85646-67738

The information I am particularly interested in is under "Payment Options", specifically on in the "wheel chart" where Principal & Interest, Property Tax, and Home Insurance values are listed and graphically displayed. I have inspected the element for this page, and it seems to me that the CSS selector I need is:

span #principle_interest .float-right

I am not sure if it is appropriate to have spaces in the above, but have tried both ways. Following is my R code:

```
## Load rvest package
library(rvest)
## Parse realtor.com page html
siteHTML <- read_html("http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/2419-Hart-Ave_Des-Moines_IA_50320_M85646-67738")
## Attempt to extract principle interest value
PBI <- siteHTML %>% html_nodes("span#principle_interest.float-right")
```

After this attempt, PBI is equal to "{xml_nodeset (0)}"

My attempts extracting the address, including city and zip code, as well as total price, number of baths, beds, square feet and lot square feet were all successful, but I could not get this part to work. Does anyone have any insight here? I sincerely apologize if this is a double post, I couldn't find anything similar upon looking around. Am I strongly oversimplifying the CSS perhaps?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I could be incorrect on this as I haven't scraped a page before but the information your looking for was likely built by a JS module/script. If so, I would look into how you scrape dynamically loaded/generated content. I'm  assuming your request is only going to return the source markup for the page.

Comment: Thank you very much, hungerstar! I will head that direction and update here with my findings.

Comment: R is not the language you want to do this in. phantomjs is a good candidate for getting dynamic content from a web page: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Thank you, quinn - will check out the link. I am currently learning about phantomjs.